# Arithmetic overflow when using atoi() on argv[1] in C

Tags: c, buffer, flags, argv, atoi

I am using `atoi(argv[1])` Here is a snippet of my code

```
void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int evenOrOdd = 0;
    int inputtedNum = 0;

    pid_t  pid;
    int    i;
    char   buf[BUF_SIZE];

    if (argc != 2)//make sure user has input correctly entered
    {
        printf("Please use input: ./a.out #\n");
    }
    else
    {
        inputtedNum = atoi(argv[1]);
        if(inputtedNum < 0) //make sure number is positive
        {
            printf("Please use a positive number.\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

The code goes on and whatnot, but when entering some numbers, it will sometimes believe they're negative. If I enter 123456789 it will have no problem and run the program correctly. If I enter 12345678910 It will think the number is a negative number. Am I running into some buffer error here to where the negative flag flops? I'm not quite certain how to fix it.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: `12345678910` is beyond the range of int32_t.

Comment: Most likely your integer is 32 bits, which only allows it to contain numbers up to 2^31-1.

Comment: Thank you Joachim. Turns out that is my highest number.

Comment: To examine the errno using strtol If you are going to test results of whether the transformation overflow. Expected range that can be input How much?

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a relatively narrow integer type, and also it is a signed type. Use `unsigned long` for `inputtedNum` and `strtoul(argv[1], 0, 0)` to parse the number.

Comment: `unsigned long` will only increase the positive range from 2G to 4G, so it will not solve the problem for a number such as 12345678910.

Comment: attempted changing to unsigned long and using strtoul, and it didn't work like barak manos said.

Comment: Then look up the manual and find out that you may use `unsigned long long` and `strtoull`. If this doesn't work, your numbers are just too big for integer types on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

On most compilers, the largest non-negative integer type supported in C is a 64-bit unsigned integer.

12345678910 cannot be stored in the `int` type that you are using, even if it was `unsigned long`.

You can solve this issue by "dividing" the input string in `argv[1]` into two strings, when it is longer than 8 digits, use `atoi` on each string, and combine the results into an `unsigned long long` variable.

This will extend your positive range from approximately 4 billion, to the largest 16-decimal-digit number.

From `main`, call `readNum(argv[1])`:

```
unsigned long long readNum(const char* input)
{
    int length = strlen(input);
    if (length <= 8)
    {
        return atoi(input);
    }
    else if (length <= 16)
    {
        char str1[8+1] = {0};
        char str2[8+1] = {0};
        memcpy(str1,input,8);
        memcpy(str2,input+8,length-8);
        return 100000000ULL*atoi(str1)+atoi(str2);
    }
    return 10000000000000000ULL; // Invalid input
}
```

Keep in mind that in order to print an `unsigned long long`, you need to use `printf` with `%llu`.

Comment: Your first statement is pragmatically true on most current CPUs, but not a correct characterization of the standard.  I suspect there are CPUs where `uintmax_t` is 128 bits; if not, it is not hard to imagine such machines.

Comment: Well, correct. Also, `unsigned long` by itself may be 64 bits on some compilers... Though, I believe that the main focus in the question at hand is the actual string-to-number conversion, rather than the official standard of types in C. So I chose to focus on a solution to the conversion issue, rather than on the size of each type according to the standard for C compilers.